# addMarker doesn't work . to show address in android maps fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, marker

i want to show a simple address in the maps .
    i followed all the steps, create MapsActivity, create Fragment ...
    but the result remain the same , i get a global map without any marker any address (please see attachment)  .

[the result- screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTMCA.png)

```
and here my code :

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static oukarroum.myapplication2.R.drawable.marker;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(44.797283, 20.460663), 12));

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(44.797283, 20.460663))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

    }


}


 my acitvity_Maps.xml :



<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="oukarroum.myapplication2.MapsActivity" />



my androidManifest.xml  :



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xxxx.myapplication2">

<!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
    <activity android:name=".CustomersList">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAxxxxxx />

    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

</application>

</manifest>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQdwN.png
```

Comment: download https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples ,here you can find all of the updated stuff you want related googlemapapiv2.

Comment: Hi momo is this  " <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAxxxxxx />" what your actual code has ? or did you hide the value for the post ?

Comment: any idea        ?
i'm still blocked

Answer (score 0):

This once happend to me also, I had to ask the user for permission,because I was  using android M to test. check if this is your case.

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }}
```

Comment: thank you for you response ,
it's already done, here i put XXXXX just to not show my key to public .

Comment: what api version are you using ?android